# PayPal REST API Payment::get doesn't return Phone

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Basically, I'm creating an Order Management system and need to retrieve the "Payer" phone number. However in the JSON Response there is none... Does paypal simply not return this? The sand boxed buyer account I setup to test with has two phone numbers on record. Yet they phone # is not returned when make the Payment::get() request.

```
{
"id": "PAY-5L1626419H036282VKVFYNAQ",
"create_time": "2015-05-07T15:36:34Z",
"update_time": "2015-05-07T15:36:45Z",
"state": "approved",
"intent": "sale",
"payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "status": "VERIFIED",
    "payer_info": {
        "email": "moca66-buyer@live.com",
        "first_name": "test",
        "last_name": "buyer",
        "payer_id": "G33XSXSD68SKL",
        "shipping_address": {
            "line1": "1 Main St",
            "city": "San Jose",
            "state": "CA",
            "postal_code": "95131",
            "country_code": "US",
            "recipient_name": "test buyer"
        }
    }
},
"transactions": [
    {
        "amount": {
            "total": "12.94",
            "currency": "USD",
            "details": {
                "subtotal": "4.99",
                "tax": "0.35",
                "shipping": "7.60"
            }
        },
        "description": "Payment description",
        "invoice_number": "554b86812d73f",
        "item_list": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": "This item is a test for shipping calculation",
                    "price": "4.99",
                    "currency": "USD",
                    "quantity": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "related_resources": [
            {
                "sale": {
                    "id": "8M4317138Y452345R",
                    "create_time": "2015-05-07T15:36:34Z",
                    "update_time": "2015-05-07T15:36:45Z",
                    "amount": {
                        "total": "12.94",
                        "currency": "USD"
                    },
                    "payment_mode": "INSTANT_TRANSFER",
                    "state": "completed",
                    "protection_eligibility": "ELIGIBLE",
                    "protection_eligibility_type": "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE",
                    "parent_payment": "PAY-5L1626419H036282VKVFYNAQ",
                    "transaction_fee": {
                        "value": "0.68",
                        "currency": "USD"
                    },
                    "links": [
                        {
                            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/8M4317138Y452345R",
                            "rel": "self",
                            "method": "GET"
                        },
                        {
                            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/8M4317138Y452345R/refund",
                            "rel": "refund",
                            "method": "POST"
                        },
                        {
                            "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5L1626419H036282VKVFYNAQ",
                            "rel": "parent_payment",
                            "method": "GET"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
],
"links": [
    {
        "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-5L1626419H036282VKVFYNAQ",
        "rel": "self",
        "method": "GET"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn on the phone number settings in the seller account . You can set it up here :

https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments

[image]

Once you turn that on , You should get the phone number too in response like below :

```
{
  "id": "PAY-43P312788Y877032MKVFZAHI",
  "create_time": "2015-05-07T16:17:33Z",
  "update_time": "2015-05-07T16:18:33Z",
  "state": "approved",
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "status": "VERIFIED",
    "payer_info": {
      "email": "XXXXXXXXX",
      "first_name": "XXXXXPersonal Test",
      "last_name": "Account",
      "payer_id": "XXXXXX",
      "shipping_address": {
        "line1": "593 Mill Street",
        "city": "Greenville",
        "postal_code": "29611",
        "country_code": "DE",
        "recipient_name": "Paypal Test"
      },
      "phone": "408-767-7151"
    }
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "total": "7.47",
        "currency": "USD",
        "details": {
          "subtotal": "7.47"
        }
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description.",
      "related_resources": [
        {
          "sale": {
            "id": "2J742201JN363443E",
            "create_time": "2015-05-07T16:17:33Z",
            "update_time": "2015-05-07T16:18:33Z",
            "amount": {
              "total": "7.47",
              "currency": "USD"
            },
            "payment_mode": "INSTANT_TRANSFER",
            "state": "completed",
            "protection_eligibility": "ELIGIBLE",
            "protection_eligibility_type": "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE",
            "parent_payment": "PAY-43P312788Y877032MKVFZAHI",
            "transaction_fee": {
              "value": "0.52",
              "currency": "USD"
            },
            "links": [
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/2J742201JN363443E",
                "rel": "self",
                "method": "GET"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/2J742201JN363443E/refund",
                "rel": "refund",
                "method": "POST"
              },
              {
                "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-43P312788Y877032MKVFZAHI",
                "rel": "parent_payment",
                "method": "GET"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "href": "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-43P312788Y877032MKVFZAHI",
      "rel": "self",
      "method": "GET"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hi @Eshan. May I ask what is the connection of sandbox account and the developer's account?  I think the one that we need is the developer's account, since the client and secret id is located there and not in the sandbox account?